# then() is called even though error is occured

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Following code makes me confused

```
doSomething()
.then(doSomethingElse())
    .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
        System.out.println("Error occurred");
        return Mono.empty();
    })

private Mono<Void> doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Error thrown");
    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException());
}

private Mono<Void> doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("doSomethingElse");
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

output:

```
Error thrown
doSomethingElse
Error occurred
```

Why then() is called when error is returned, shouldn't it be skipped? I expect following output:

```
Error thrown
Error occurred
```

What is proper way to achieve expected behavior? In other words, then() should be called only when doSomeError doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: Read the documentation on .then() https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then--. What it does it forward completion or error. As you are giving it an error it just emits it. This method is useful when you don't care about the data but only about the result (ok/error).

Answer (score 1):

Since doSomethingElse is called during the creation of the stream itself, you sould change the function as follows to get the expected result;

```
   private Mono<Void> doSomethingElse() {
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
            System.out.println("doSomethingElse");
            return null;
        });
    }
```

Comment: alternatively, `return Mono.defer(() -> { System.out.println("doSomethingElse"); return Mono.empty(); };` but that's a matter of preference / readability mostly